# Python continously receive message through websocket

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to connect through websocket and keeping it alive to retrieve continously message from the server. I wrote the clientHelper and find the socketManager and ReconnectingWebsocket on the internet and I have not much idea on what going wrong with it as I do not receive anything thought the clientHelper.process_user_message function.

Can someone point me out the error please?

```
import websockets as ws
import asyncio
from client import Client

class ClientHelper(Client):
   def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
      super().__init__(api_key, api_secret)
      self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

   def _request(self, method, uri, signed, force_params=False, **kwargs):
       kwargs = self._get_request_kwargs(method, signed, force_params, **kwargs)
       response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
       return self._handle_response(response, method)

   def _request(self, method, path, signed=False, version=API_VERSION, **kwargs):
       uri = self._create_api_uri(path, signed, version)
       return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)

   def get_listen_key(self):
        res = self._request('post', 'userDataStream', signed=True, data={})
        return res['listenKey']

   async def start_websockets(self):        
      self.sm = SocketManager(self, self.loop)
      await self.sm.start_socket(self.process_user_message)

   async def process_user_message(self, msg):
      self.msg = msg
      print(msg)

   async def main(self)
      await self.start_websockets()
      while True:
          await client.getInfo()
          if 'data' in self.msg:
              print(self.msg['data'])

    def start(self):
       self.loop.run_until_complete(self.main())

class SocketManager:
   STREAM_URL = url

   def __init__(self, client, loop, user_timeout=DEFAULT_USER_TIMEOUT):
      self._client = client
      self._loop = loop
      self._conns = None

   async def _start_user_socket(self, path, coro, prefix='ws/'):
        if path in self._conns:
            return False

        self._conns[path] = ReconnectingWebsocket(self._loop, path, coro, prefix)

        return path

   async def start_user_socket(self, coro):
        user_listen_key = await self._client.stream_get_listen_key() # manage to get the key from serveur
        conn_key = await self._start_user_socket('user', user_listen_key, coro)
        return conn_key

class ReconnectingWebsocket:
    STREAM_URL = url
    MAX_RECONNECTS = 5
    MAX_RECONNECT_SECONDS = 60
    MIN_RECONNECT_WAIT = 0.1
    TIMEOUT = 10

    def __init__(self, loop, path, coro, prefix='ws/'):
        self._loop = loop
        self._log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self._path = path
        self._coro = coro
        self._prefix = prefix
        self._reconnects = 0
        self._conn = None
        self._socket = None
        self._connect()

    def _connect(self):
        self._conn = asyncio.ensure_future(self._run(), loop=self._loop)

    async def _run(self):
        keep_waiting = True

        async with ws.connect(self.STREAM_URL) as socket:
            self._socket = socket
            self._reconnects = 0
            
            try:
                while keep_waiting:
                    try:
                        #evt = await self._coro(evt_obj)
                        evt = await asyncio.wait_for(self._socket.recv(), timeout=self.TIMEOUT)
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        #self._log.debug("no message in {} seconds".format(self.TIMEOUT))
                        print("no message in {} seconds".format(self.TIMEOUT))
                        await self.send_ping()
                    except asyncio.CancelledError:
                        #self._log.debug("cancelled error")
                        print("cancelled error")
                        await self.send_ping()
                    else:
                        try:
                            evt_obj = json.loads(evt)
                        except ValueError:
                            #self._log.debug('error parsing evt json:{}'.format(evt))
                            print('error parsing evt json:{}'.format(evt))
                        else:
                            await self._coro(evt_obj)
            except ws.ConnectionClosed as e:
                #self._log.debug('ws connection closed:{}'.format(e))
                print('ws connection closed:{}'.format(e))
                await self._reconnect()
            except Exception as e:
                #self._log.debug('ws exception:{}'.format(e))
                print('ws exception:{}'.format(e))
                await self._reconnect()
            
    def _get_reconnect_wait(self, attempts: int) -> int:
        expo = 2 ** attempts
        return round(random() * min(self.MAX_RECONNECT_SECONDS, expo - 1) + 1)

    async def _reconnect(self):
        await self.cancel()
        self._reconnects += 1
        if self._reconnects < self.MAX_RECONNECTS:
            reconnect_wait = self._get_reconnect_wait(self._reconnects)
            await asyncio.sleep(reconnect_wait)
            self._connect()
        else:
            self._log.error('Max reconnections {} reached:'.format(self.MAX_RECONNECTS))

    async def send_ping(self):
        if self._socket:
            await self._socket.ping()

    async def cancel(self):
        self._conn.cancel()
        self._socket = None
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect in syntax and semantics: it uses `Class` instead of `class`, imports a `Client` module and then uses it as a base class, has an unfinished `main()`, and so on. `process_user_message` cannot run because you only pass it to a non-existent `SocketManager.start_socket` method; the class has a private `_start_socket` which accepts completely different parameters. Please don't take it the wrong way, but I suggest avoiding code from the internet that you don't understand. Instead, start with snippets from the `websockets` docs and implement the needed functionality from there.

Comment: Okay, my bad, I made mistakes while copy-pasting the code. The start_socket does exist of course. The code is super long so I don't want to drop some useless functions here

Comment: You are still sending different number and kinds of parameters to `start_socket` than the ones it expects. Also, the `whlie` loop in `main()` doesn't `await` anything, so it blocks the whole event loop.

Comment: I have updated again. I am not sure what you mean about it should await in the while loop though.. I just want to have an open socket with the serveur and everytime it pushes a message I save it in self.msg, et a just wanted to print every second to check it is different.

Comment: Regarding `await` in `while`: Printing every second is fine, then you'd have `await asyncio.sleep(1)` (or equivalent) in the loop. But as previouslyl written, the `while` loop in `main` didn't contain any `await` expression, which practically guaranteed that it would block asyncio. Asyncio is based on cooperative multitasking, and any callback or coroutine it executes must eventually `await` something (or return).

Comment: This version of the code looks like something that has a chance of working - I see no obvious issues. Have you tried adding debugging prints to check where it gets "stuck", i.e. why it doesn't reach `process_user_message`?

Comment: How could I do to wait for next message in the async def process_user_message(self, msg)? cause I want to trigger something as soon as it get a new message.

Comment: So I get the user_listen_key , but then no messages are printed from process_user_message